# Using a Grid background image in a container

Tags: html, css

I'm using the skeleton framework to build a site,and during the design I want to put a 960px grid image as a background because it's easier for me to structure all the elements.

But if I put the grid image as the body background, the image doesn't match with the 960px container and if I put the grid image as the background of the 960px container, the image doesn't shows up in the browser.

Probably this is very easy but I'm not seeing how to do it.

Any other tips about how to see the grid during the designing process are also welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Which css framework are you using?

Comment: Why not just use css borders to show their outlines?

Comment: I'm using the Skeleton framework: http://www.getskeleton.com/ My goal is to have the grid image as a background like I use in photoshop

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: My goal is to see the container of this grid (960px): https://github.com/dhgamache/Skeleton/blob/master/stylesheets/skeleton.css with this image as a background: http://www.clickn.com.br/repositorio/nathansmith-960-Grid-System-179cfd9/nathansmith-960-Grid-System-179cfd9/templates/fireworks/960_grid_16_col.png. When I add the grid background to container class selector the grid doesn't appear in the browser.

Comment: Can you not just set it as the background of the body centered on the page?

Comment: Thanks, now that's working. I don't know why but that wasn't working before. It only works when I set the background directly in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your container in a div with your background. Then just put your content in the container div. Quite Simple, MANY OTHER WAYS TO DO THIS, this is my preferred way as in future designs you will notice padding and margin issue when adding stuff to container divs

```
.wrapper {

background-image: url ('../YOURSITE/IMAGE.JPG');
width: 960px;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.container {

width: 960px;
}

<html>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="container">

</div>
<!--end container-->
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->

</html>
</body>
```

Comment: In your case add .. to the front of your image file in your css, see my edit above.